# Update BLAST+ to v.13.0+ and set the path permanently

Tags: path, blast

I have on my Linux computer the blast version v.12.0+ and would like to install the up to date version: v.13.0+.

I am having trouble with setting the PATH to this new version. Indeed, when I enter the following command in a terminal:

```
export PATH=/home/administrateur/ncbi-blast-2.13.0+/bin
```

it works great until I close my terminal.

I would like to set it **permanently** so that everytime I open a new terminal, the command line:

```
blastn -version
```

returns 2.13.0+ instead of 2.12.0+ ..

Could you please help me?

Many thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone wondering, the following solution worked for me:**

I printed the path of the blast directory I have downloaded (in the bin subfolder) :

```
pwd -P
```

and it returned:

```
/home/blast/ncbi-blast-2.13.0+/bin
```

I openned the bashrc file using:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and I added the following line at the end of this text file:

```
export PATH=/home/blast/ncbi-blast-2.13.0+/bin:$PATH
```

I saved this file and sourced it using:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and whenever I open a new terminal and type:

```
blastn -version
```

It returns:

```
blastn: 2.13.0+
```

Hope it helps!